# How to make a div span two rows (only on mobile layout)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a responsive web layout based on bootstrap. I have Glyphs, titles and text. These are my two layouts:

[1A]          [1B]        [1C]

[2A]          [2B]        [2C]

[3A]          [3B]        [3C]

This is the layout for small screens.

[1A]  [2A] 
            [3A]

[1B]  [2B] 
            [3B]

[1C]  [2C] 
            [3C]

This code makes the first layout, but how do I achieve the second responsively?

## EDIT:

I have this:

[image]

From this code:
CSS:

```
.green-box {
    background: #3DBEAF;
    border: 5px solid #e7e7e7;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 2.77778%
}
@media (max-width: 769px) {
.mob-hide{
    display: none;  
}
.green-box{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 green-box eqheight1">
      <div class="glyphicon-ring"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn glyphicon-bordered" /></div>
      <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-12">
        <h3>Revolutionary</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-12">
        <p class>Knowing when to change a gas bottle isn't always easy so many people buy a back-up or risk running out unexpectedly is a real pain - it might leave you cold or with hungry in-laws, either way it will spoil your day. Meet Gas-Sense!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 margin mob-hide"></div>
<!-- Other two boxes -->
</div
```

How do I get the glyph on the left, and centered in the middle vertically of the title text block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just going off your diagram:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-12">The X icon in the diagram</div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-12">
            The article text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have edited my question showing the result of your answer, but how do I get the glyph on the left and vertically centered in the whole block (responsively)?

Comment: this is what my example does. Look at the col-sm-*. You will see that the outer div just has col-sm-12 i.e. it takes up the whole width of the screen. The inner containers then have col-sm-3 and col-sm-9, so the div with the icon in takes up 1/4 of the horizontal space and the div with the article text takes up the remaining 3/4 of the horizontal space.

Comment: To center vertically you can use one of several methods, search for "centering in css". The most useful is usually to set the line-height or to wrap in a div with display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle (which itself must be wrapped in a div with display: table)

Answer (score 1):

You need group each icon, text and heading together, then add some classes for `col-xs-*`:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RreRrN

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-12">
        <div class="glyphicon-ring"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"/></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-12">
        <h2>Title 1</h2>
        <p>Text 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-12">
        <div class="glyphicon-ring"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"/></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-12">
        <h2>Title 2</h2>
        <p>Text 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-12">
        <div class="glyphicon-ring"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"/></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-12">
        <h2>Title 3</h2>
        <p>Text 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I can't really see from the demo how this is working?

Comment: I suggest reading up on how the bootstrap grid system works. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: I understand the theory of bootstrap, I just don't get how your solution solves my problem. Please check my question update to make sure I have explained the desired outcome properly.

Comment: The drawing is different to the text based layout you posted (this wasn't all that clear though, so I've probably misunderstood this too)

Comment: Sorry about that, I have changed the spacing on the question to make it clearer. So do you know how to produce that result, or am I still explaining it badly?

Comment: ok, i see what you're trying to do. you're approaching this wrong, You need to thinking of the pictures as one group, and the heading + text as another. You need to group these as 3 lots of icon/title/text. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: Great, thank you! How do I ensure the glyph column extends the same height at the other two title and text, so it is vertically centered?

Comment: That's a different question. Have a go at doing it yourself, Google some solutions and if you're stuck, post another question.

Comment: if you look at the title and diagram, it is the original question.